# Using a different profile with eclipse and counterclockwise on leiningen

Tags: eclipse, clojure, leiningen, counterclockwise

I'm using Counterclockwise eclipse plugin on a leiningen Clojure project. I need to run a repl from Eclipse and make it load a different leiningen project than the default. Since the default one is being loaded, I get multiple classpath errors on dependencies that are on the profile I want to use, but not on the default profile. Anyone knows how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't with the latest version of counterclockwise (0.27).
I managed to get it to work with IntelliJ and La Clojure using maven export of the project.